# Different outputs while printing ArrayList in java

Tags: java, collections

Review last 2 lines of both outputs why different?
I am satisfied with program 1

Program 1

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    al.add(10);
    al.add(20);
    al.add(30);
    System.out.println(al);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------");

    al.addAll(2, al);                                                       
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
    System.out.println(al);

    System.out.println(al.get(2).getClass());
}

Output :

[10, 20, 30]
-----------------------------------
-----------------------------------
**[10, 20, 10, 20, 30, 30]
class java.lang.Integer**
```

***I am unsatisfied with program 2 output 
Why different output while printing arraylist?
why "java.util.ArrayList" is last line of output for prog 2 but "java.lang.Integer" for prog1***

Program 2

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        al.add(10);
        al.add(20);
        al.add(30);
        System.out.println(al);
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");

        al.add(2,al);                                                   
        al.add(8);                                                         
        al.add(2);                                                      
        al.add(4);                                                      
        al.add(1);                                                      
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        System.out.println(al);
        System.out.println(al.get(2).getClass());
    }

Output : 

[10, 20, 30]
-----------------------------------
-----------------------------------
[10, 20, (this Collection), 30, 8, 2, 4, 1]
class java.util.ArrayList
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `al.add(2, al);`, you almost certainly want `al.addAll(2, al);`, which will add the *contents* of `al` (as it stands before that method call is complete) to `al`.

At present, you're just adding an `ArrayList` object to the list, and since your `ArrayList` can contain any old thing due to lack of generic parameters (not desirable!), this compiles and runs just fine.

You're running into this issue because you're using a generic `ArrayList` without any generic parameters. If you were explicitly using `ArrayList<Integer>`, then that line as it stands wouldn't compile. Using it without such parameters is only supported for legacy, backwards compatibility reasons, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

In Program 2, the line:

```
al.add(2,al);
```

adds the Arraylist 'al' to itself at index 2. The code:

```
al.get(2)
```

therefore returns an ArrayList. That's why printing the two lists returns different results.

To avoid issues like this, initialize the ArrayList with:
`ArrayList<Integer>`

Answer (score 1):

First of All your `ArrayList` is a raw type that can take any **heterogeneous** objects into it.

Here, `ArrayList` is raw type so even a `String` Object can also be added to this `ArrayList` Object `al`.

```
al.add("something");
al.add(25.4D);
al.add(new Foo());  //these all possible Object can be added to this ArrayList.
```

In your second Example you have added using `add(index, element)` method. and if you see the definition of add(index, element)`in Class`ArrayList`.

You will find this.

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
        rangeCheckForAdd(index);
        ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index, elementData, index + 1,
                         size - index);
        elementData[index] = element;  //take a look at this statement.
        size++;
    }
```

At line number 5

```
elementData[index] = element; // element directly put into the collection.
```

So, reference of `al` directly put into the `ArrayList`, and this must be added because there is no such TypeSafety Argument provided during declaration.

It must be something like

```
ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<>(); // this may prone to compiler time error.
```

> **Note** : Please also take a look of `add(index, Element)` and `addAll(Collection c)` definition from `JavaDocs`.